# Generate week schedule report from SQL

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, pdf-generation, report

Given a database table of appointments I want to print a report (PDF or printer) showing each day of the week with the appointments in order of their scheduled time.

The database table looks like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENTS  (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR (50),
    Date DATE,
    Time TIME);
```

The output should look like this:

[image: The desired output report]

I have been generating the report by coding it using 2D graphics operations (rectangles, text out, etc.), but this is tedious and hard to change.

What is the easiest way to go from SQL to such a report? The less programming involved, the better. I don't care about the programming language in case needed, the report generation will run standalone.

Edit: Even though I don't care about the platform/language, I don't need a platform independent solution.

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged "language agnostic" but I would suggest narrowing it down a little to at least the OS, if not the language.

If the Windows platform is acceptable, then MS SQL Reporting Services has options which are completely free and allow report creation with little or no programming (other than the query). The reports are then delivered via a website and can be exported as PDFs.

The database type itself shouldn't matter to SQL Reporting Services (SSRS) as long as there is an ODBC driver available. Of course, if you are running in a completely non-Windows environment then I probably wouldn't go this route.

Here are a couple calendar-style reports in SSRS which look similar to what you have shown:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/#hr

http://rduclos.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/ssrs-2008-generate-calendars-based-on-a-date-range/

These articles use rather verbose `UNIONs`. I would probably use the `PIVOT` keyword in MS SQL instead, but the result would be the same.

Comment: Can you be more specific how to get this done in MS SQL Reporting Services? I have not found any reporting solution, which provides for the kind of grid necessary for the above report.

Comment: Sure. I'm not a reporting guru but I believe a tablix in SSRS would work. Essentially you can pivot rows into columns. Alternatively, it may be easiest to pivot at the database level and just let the reporting tool bind to a simple data table. Or, a combination of methods (like pivot at the DB but perform additional calculations inside the reporting tool).

Comment: Thanks Tim. For the report, no union should be necessary, because individual cells are not aggregated.

Comment: What the links you give, don't get right is that they show each day as a fixed box, but my reports need flexible amount of space in each day because there can be any number of appointments.

Comment: I believe the first link shows multiple appointments in a single day (at least in this image: http://www.simple-talk.com/iwritefor/articlefiles/835-SSRS.h12.jpg). SSRS has quite a few aggregation options, although making them work correctly can be a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a vote in for [Jasper Reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports), a Java-based reporting stack. You can create reports with desktop-based applications such as iReport, and upload them to the default Jasper web application. Reports can be generated immediately, or can be set to generate periodically and be sent to an email address. There's a permissions system too so that various roles in your organisation get access to the right reports.

Jasper also contains a SOAP engine if you want to access the reporting service programmatically - I developed a 'background reporting' service for long-running reports this way, called from PHP.

All of this software is available under F/OSS licenses, but you'd need to be confident setting up and running a Java application. I believe the instance I used to work on ran under Glassfish, but Tomcat would work.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the report shown above in iReport? They don't seem to have a matrix / tabilix component.

Comment: It's been a while, but my guess is that you need a [CrossTab](http://bekwam.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/expanding-crosstab-in-jaspersoft.html). I'm quite sure that iReport can do it.

Comment: Addendum: if you are generating this daily, you may be able to script something with iReport on its own, rather than needing to set up Jasper too. I imagine you could run iReport from the CLI, specifying a print flag and a filename, and it prints the latest version without any extra effort.

Comment: A CrossTab only aggregates several values to a sum, product, count, etc (for instance Sales aggregated by Country). It does not help for the problem at hand.

Comment: Righty-ho. I can't say with any _certainty_ that it will fulfil your needs, as I haven't spent sufficient time with it. Nevertheless I think it would be worth your spending a little time on this approach, if it would otherwise fit into your stack; I know it fulfilled every reporting requirement my colleagues threw at it, and it is free to use.